# Typescript Partial<T> causing undefined error even with `?` chaining or conditional Checks

Tags: typescript, mongoose, mongoose-schema, typescript-generics, typescript-utility

I have a mongoose document stored as follows:

```
const currentGuildAlerts: Partial<mongoose.Document<IServerSchema> | null> = await Server.findOne(query).exec();
```

With the use of `Partial<T>` (as i only getting a single path from the `IServerSchema` returned from the query), I understand that `Partial` chains a `?` to the end of each property in the interface. But i should be able to get around it by using a conditional check for the value right?

```
if(currentGuildAlerts) currentGuildAlerts.get("symbol_alerts").btc_alerts;
```

This still gives me the error : `Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.`

I even tried to do

```
currentGuildAlerts?.get("symbol_alerts").btc_alerts;
```

Still doesn't seem to solve the problem. What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Partial` means that the ***properties*** of an object might be `undefined`.  You are making sure that the `currentGuildAlerts` *object* isn't `null` but you haven't checked that the *property* exists.

You need an optional chaining `?.` after `get` as well since you have said that all properties of the `Document` might be `undefined`.

```
const currentGuildAlerts: Partial<mongoose.Document<IServerSchema>> | null = await Server.findOne(query).exec();

const alerts = currentGuildAlerts?.get?.("symbol_alerts").btc_alerts;
```

Perhaps is makes more sense to move the `Partial` inside the `Document`?

```
const currentGuildAlerts: mongoose.Document<Partial<IServerSchema>> | null = await Server.findOne(query).exec();

const alerts = currentGuildAlerts?.get("symbol_alerts").btc_alerts;
```